# jsf java asking about time in jsf

Tags: java, jsf

my data base have simple date and time but when i pic in UI so time is convert in to GMT .
How to convert origional time(DB) .

Comment: I'm not sure what "pic in UI" means, and it sounds important to the question - you may want to revisit this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<f:convertDateTime/>`

Example:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.myDate}">
  <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```

More info about `<f:convertDateTime/>` can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSFPage7.html#wp127668).

Comment: i use this but time is comming in GMT not actual time which is in data base

Comment: <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm"  /> use this

Comment: @vivek - what do you mean "coming in GMT time"?  An instance of time is a specific point in time that is unambiguous; it can be **expressed as a string** in multiple formats, one of which is GMT, but the actual **time** you receive will be identical to the one stored in the database.  (How your DB querying tool *displays* that time is independent from the value stored in the database.)